# Uninstalling apps doesn't free up much space

Tags: software-uninstall

When I for example run

```
sudo apt autoremove blender
```

It doesn't uninstall all blender files it just deletes around 10~20 mb of files

Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: Traditionally, deb-packaged applications take up very little storage. There are often much easier ways to free up storage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is
I had this problem for years and I couldn't solve it with any other solution but a day I I noticed when I want to install a software with apt or Deb file it says some new packages are going to be installed and just one of them is for example blender.

For playonlinux before installation it says :

`The following additional packages will be installed: curl icoutils jq libjq1 libonig5 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 python3-natsort python3-numpy python3-wxgtk4.0 Suggested packages: libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl scrot ttf-mscorefonts-installer winbind python-natsort-doc gfortran python-numpy-doc python3-dev python3-pytest wx3.0-doc The following NEW packages will be installed: curl icoutils jq libjq1 libonig5 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 playonlinux python3-natsort python3-numpy python3-wxgtk4.0 0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.`

You should copy and paste 2 lines of new packages and the line of suggested packages in a text file,
Then copy the packages you copied in the text file text file should be something like :

`curl icoutils jq libjq1 libonig5 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 python3-natsort python3-numpy python3-wxgtk4.0 libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl scrot ttf-mscorefonts-installer winbind python-natsort-doc gfortran python-numpy-doc python3-dev python3-pytest wx3.0-doc curl icoutils jq libjq1 libonig5 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 playonlinux python3-natsort python3-numpy python3-wxgtk4.0 curl icoutils jq libjq1 libonig5 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 playonlinux python3-natsort python3-numpy python3-wxgtk4.0`

Then when you copied text file packages type

`sudo apt autoremove`

**but don't hit enter**

And then paste that text file packages it will be something like

`sudo apt autoremove curl icoutils jq libjq1 libonig5 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 python3-natsort python3-numpy python3-wxgtk4.0 libterm-readline-gnu-perl | libterm-readline-perl-perl scrot ttf-mscorefonts-installer winbind python-natsort-doc gfortran python-numpy-doc python3-dev python3-pytest wx3.0-doc curl icoutils jq libjq1 libonig5 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 playonlinux python3-natsort python3-numpy python3-wxgtk4.0 curl icoutils jq libjq1 libonig5 libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 playonlinux python3-natsort python3-numpy python3-wxgtk4.0`

**NOW YOU CAN PRESS ENTER**

It will uninstall all packages related to playonlinux or any other app

**ALL OF PACKAGE NAMES WAS EXAMPLE**

Comment: This doesn't make any sense... `apt autoremove` will remove every dependency not needed anymore.

Comment: But believe it didn't work for me

Comment: Then the question you should troubleshoot is WHY an ordinary `autoremove` didn't work for you. It's usually a human (self-inflicted) mistake, like specifying dependencies to install instead of letting apt handle it. Once specified, packages are not eligible for autoremove.

Comment: Try it yourself with playonlinux